# Отделение float и int от символьных знаков

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, split

У меня есть алгоритм который делит строки таким образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Меня все устраивает, кроме результата последнего слова, хотелось бы получить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно это реализовать с помощью регулярных выражений?

Comment: Пожалуйста, приводите в вопросах код в текстовом виде, а не скриншотами.

Comment: То ,что указано у Вас в примере это не int и float, а строки заключающие только цифры.Чтобы провериться содержит ли строка только цифры используйте `string.isdigit()`.Хотя здесь лучше регулярки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```py
print(re.split('([^\d.]+)', s))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
words=['14мм', '130mm', 'NUM-T2', '14 мм', '20 sec', '9.14']
for i in words:
    finds = re.findall(r'([\d\.]+|\D+)', i)
    print (finds)

['14', 'мм']
['130', 'mm']
['NUM-T', '2']
['14', ' мм']
['20', ' sec']
['9.14']
```